# Post file directly from byte array in ASP.net

Tags: asp.net, file, post, upload

How do you replicate a traditional POST form (file post) in code, the end goal is to stream a byte array as the file into the posted form, the example below is the form that I am trying to replicate in code.

```
    <form method="POST" action="http://export.writer.zoho.com/remotedoc.im?apikey=[apikey]&output=editor" enctype="multipart/form-data" target="_self">
<input type="file" name="content" size="38"> <br>
<input type="hidden" name="filename" value="mydocument.doc">
<input type="hidden" name="saveurl" value="[REMOTE SERVER SAVE URL]">
<input type="hidden" name="id" value="12345678">
<input type="hidden" name="format" value="doc">
<input type="submit" value="Edit" class="divbutton" name="submit">
</form>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is done using HttpWebRequestClass , an example of how to do this can be found here http://netomatix.com/HttpPostData.aspx

Comment: I have read through that article but I cannot see how I would incorporate the file data, from what I can tell the values are concatenated into the request, it doesn't seem like that would work for file data

Comment: Partial credit, The article didn't really help but pointing me towards using HttpWebRequest did. Thanks.

Comment: No Prob , if i had seen your reply earlier i would have mentioned that you need to send the file using a stream , if you have found a valid solution please post it here so others will find the answer easier :)